# What are the most common Greek-made cigarettes?

Tags: greece, smoking

I have the habit of buying a few packs of local cigarettes in every country I visit. However, at tobacco shops, the clerks usually aren't able to understand what I want from them (they're like "buy Marlboros").

What are typical Greece cigarettes (local only to Greece) I should buy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are six companies producing and distributing cigarettes in Greece. Karelia Tobacco and SEKAP are domestic manufacturers and the rest are subsidiaries of multinationals.

The vendors want you to buy Marlboro because they are expensive. Like when you go into a bar and ask for "a beer" they will sell a tourist the most expensive one.

Traditional brands: Karelia Filter Kasetina, Karelia Agriniou, Rex.

I believe SEKAP is a cooperative and the Cooper and GR brands are made by them.